# Reloading using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Hello friends from SO!**

I'm new into angular, and I'm trying to keep a table always updated with the information comming from a PHP webservice.

I'm demanding the information the first time using the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="block" ng-controller="demandar_informacion" ng-init="visualizacion_masiva()">
                    <h1 class="block_header">Welcome admin</h1>
                    <p class="block_info"></p>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th ng-repeat="header in headers ">{{header}}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr ng-repeat="disponible in disponibles">
                            <td ng-repeat="(variable, valor) in disponible">{{valor}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Then I'm using the following code to get the information:

**Js Angular:**

```
function demandar_informacion($scope, $http) {

        //pedido de visualización masiva
        $scope.visualizacion_masiva = function() {

            var address = "http://127.0.0.1/usa/_code/index_records.php"
            + "?ac=view_all"

            var pedido = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: address
            })

            .success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.errors = data.error;
                $scope.headers = data.headers;
                $scope.disponibles = data.disponibles;
                $scope.eliminados = data.eliminados;
                $scope.info = data.info;
            });

        };

}
```

**Main Q:**

Is there any way I could re-send the HTTP packet and update the information every, let's say, 3 or 5 seconds? as It's rapidly changing.

**Auxiliary:**

At the same time, this fragment of code, seems to be altering the order of the values I have on the array, or it might be previously altered somewhere in the Angular code. I've checked the PHP and the Json string seems to be in right conditions, but when it comes to printing the values, it completely looses it's native order (shows the elements in an improper / unknown order)... anyone has a clue?

```
<tr ng-repeat="disponible in disponibles">
                            <td ng-repeat="(variable, valor) in disponible">{{valor}}</td>
                        </tr>
```

**Thanks in advance!
Chris C. Russo**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

```
$scope.update = function() {
  $timeout(function() {
    $http.get('lol').success(function() {
      $scope.update();
    });
  }, 5000);
};
```

### Old

Simplest way to do this:

```
$interval(function() {
  demandar_informacion();
}, 5000);
```

buuuuutttt as MichaL pointed out in the comments what will happen is that 5 seconds will get eaten up as it becomes 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, DDOSing yourself due to the time it takes to complete the request.

Other ways:

- Use firebase to wait and call the load function.
- Long poll your php script.

Comment: Using $interval may be dangerous - it's better to use chained $timeout calls (if demandar_informacion execution takes more than 5s, then we're in trouble). See http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/05/14/setinterval-is-moderately-evil.aspx

Comment: @MichałDudak That's a good point a recursive function would be better.

Comment: Señores, muchas gracias. 1kg of Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $timeout service to call the server every few seconds. Or use websockets to push the changes from the server to your Angular app (with Ratchet, perhaps (http://socketo.me/))